# How can a view call a function (which is not a view) in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Is it possible to create a view/function in django that is callable only from another function I.e. the function doesn't accept any `GET`/`POST` requests.

Comment: You just call that function? In fact you probably already do that a lot. For example `render(..)` is a function you likely already called in your views.

Comment: Well that's undoubtedly correct. Maybe working for long hours had some -ve effects on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call a function in your view as you would normally do, and you can also pass all the arguments you want. It will behave just like a normal function, even though it is called from a view (You can see that the normal function is normal, because it doesn’t return an `HttpResponse` object).

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def example_view(request):
    """Example."""
    print_curr_user(request)

    return render(request, ‘some_app/some_html.html’)

# Normal function.
def print_curr_user(request):
    """Example: print current user from request object."""
    print(request.user)
```